# How to merge two data frames based on different column names

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                     'C': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1']})

right = pd.DataFrame({'AA': ['A1', 'A3'],
                      'BB': ['B0', 'B3'],
                      'CC': ['K0', 'K1'],
                      'DD': ['D0', 'D1']})
```

I want to join these two data frames by adding column `DD` to `left`. The values of `DD` should be selected based on comparing `A` and `AA`, `B` and  `BB`, `C` and `CC`.

The simple joining case would be as as shown below, but in my case I need to compare columns with different names, and then I want only add `DD` to `right`.

```
result = left.join(right, on='DD')
```

The result should be:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                       'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                       'C': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1'],
                       'DD': ['D0', NaN, NaN, 'D1']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas `merge` method with `left_on` and `right_on` parameters.

```
left.merge(right, how='left',
          left_on=['A', 'B', 'C'],
          right_on=['AA', 'BB', 'CC'])[['A', 'B', 'C', 'DD']]
```

gets you:

```
    A   B   C   DD
0  A1  B0  K0   D0
1  A1  B1  K1  NaN
2  A2  B2  K0  NaN
3  A3  B3  K1   D1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

However at the moment the columns names don't match up (A is AA in `right`).
So first let's normalize them:

```
In [11]: right.columns = right.columns.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Then we can merge on the shared columns:

```
In [12]: left.merge(right)
Out[12]:
    A   B   C   D
0  A1  B0  K0  D0
1  A3  B3  K1  D1

In [13]: left.merge(right, how="outer")
Out[13]:
    A   B   C    D
0  A1  B0  K0   D0
1  A1  B1  K1  NaN
2  A2  B2  K0  NaN
3  A3  B3  K1   D1
```

Comment: Do I also need to normalize columns of `left`?

Comment: @JoeBlack the code above is working code. but it depends what your real life example is (and why the same columns are differently labelled in different DataFrames, to me that looks like something I would want to correct before merging/starting calculations).